# Append strings with File Pointer for Bison

Tags: c++, c, file-io, bison

I wrote a simple Interpreter using Flex and Bison in C. I am reading the file to be interpreted using the Line 'yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );'. Well. Now I getting some request from browser using CGI. This is my sample data Which i receive from Broswer.

> abc="Hello"
>
> cfg="Welcome"
>
> count=10

Now I need to add these lines to my file which is to interpreted . How can I do this task ?
I tried to connect yyin with c++ file Streams. So that I can convert my data which received from browser to StringStream . And Append it with file streams. But yyin pointer only accepts I/O Pointers. Is there any other way to merge these data with my language codes ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using flex, you can use `yy_scan_string` to parse from a buffer instead of a file:

```
YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer = yy_scan_string(my_string_buffer);
yyparse();
yy_delete_buffer(buffer);
```

Here `my_string_buffer` is just a pointer to memory containing the text to be parsed as a NUL terminated string.  `yy_scan_string` makes a copy of the string (so you can reuse the buffer for something else immediately), which will be freed when you call `yy_delete_buffer`

Answer (score 1):

In a CGI environment, the input from the browser should be available through `stdin`. So you could just set `yyin = stdin;`. If you want to first parse the contents of a file (which seems odd to me, but I'm sure you have your reasons), then you need to use `yywrap` as described in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-yywrap_0028_0029):

> When the scanner receives an end-of-file indication from `YY_INPUT`, it then checks the `yywrap()` function. If `yywrap()` returns false (zero), then it is assumed that the function has gone ahead and set up `yyin` to point to another input file, and scanning continues. If it returns true (non-zero), then the scanner terminates, returning 0 to its caller. Note that in either case, the start condition remains unchanged; it does not revert to `INITIAL`.

Of course, you need to remember to only do that once. Something like this might work:

```
int yywrap() {
  if (yyin == stdin) return 1;
  yyin = stdin;
  return 0;
}
```

However, it is not quite that simple to read a POST request in a CGI environment. Typically you need to ensure that you do not read beyond the end of the body, by being aware of the specified content length and/or chunked encoding. As indicated in the cited chapter of the flex manual, you can redefine the `YYINPUT` macro in order to provide a customized input-reader.